# Access a bash script variable outside the docker container in which the script is running

Tags: bash, shell, docker

I have a bash script running inside a docker container. In this script, I set the value of some variable.

**Can I somehow access the value of this variable outside the container?**

I tried to make the variable "global" but could not figure out how to do it. Is it a good idea to make the required variable an environment variable inside the container?

**How to reproduce**

Create a bash script called `temp.sh` with the following contents:

```sh
a=$RANDOM
```

Now, run this file in a docker container as follows:

```
 docker run -it --rm -v $(pwd):/opt alpine sh -c "sh /opt/temp.sh"
```

**Desired behaviour**: To be able to access the variable `a` outside the docker container

Comment: You could write the variable in a file for other processes to read, or stuff it in a Redis instance where any other process on the network can read it. Redis is a data structure server that can share strings, atomic integers, queues, lists, hashes and sets across a network.

Comment: Can i have this file to be located on the host filesystem?

Comment: You could share a filesystem between the host and container https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

Comment: It might help you to think of the container as being a separate computer; thus, any methods that would help you get the value of `a` outside the container are more or less the same as the methods you'd use to send it to another computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit: [This comment by Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164015/access-a-bash-script-variable-outside-the-docker-container-in-which-the-script-i?noredirect=1#comment102710057_58164015)

1. I mounted a directory on the docker filesystem using

`docker run -v <host-file-system-directory>:<docker-file-system-directory>`

2. In the bash script, I added 
   `echo "$variable" >docker-file-system-directory/variable.txt`
3. As I had mounted a host filesystem directory on the docker filesystem, I can still access `variable.txt` simply using `cat <host-file-system-directory>/variable.txt`

**Note that *`docker-file-system-directory`* must be an absolute path, and not a relative path.**

Comment: Well done - thank you for sharing your solution. Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving that is using `docker exec`, if your container is running and has access to bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
set -x
yourContainerName="testContainerName"
test=$(docker exec -i "${yourContainerName}" bash <<EOF
# do some work here e.g. execute your script
testVar="thisIsTest" # the value we want to access outside of container
echo \$testVar
EOF
)
echo $test
```

We pass a multiline script to docker container, which in the end echo's the value we need. This value is then accessible from shell that executed `docker exec`.

Output looks like this:

```
++ docker exec -i testContainerName bash
+ test=thisIsTest
+ echo thisIsTest
thisIsTest
```