# Link a docker container folder to a host folder

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I am new to docker and I am trying to do the following: I would like to have a folder on my host machine which is synched with a folder in the Docker container. I need this since I would like to write on some files of the container folder with the usual software tools I use on my host machine (e.g., sublime text, vscode). Then, once I am done editing the files on my host computer, I will compile them in the docker container and test them directly there.

My workflow is the following:

1. In the DOCKERFILE I clone a git repository, let's call it repo1 and it will then be in the docker container in `/root/repo1`
2. I build the container (and I remove the old ones, not important for this question)
3. 

```
# Run docker, setup and keep running
echo Running docker, setting it up and keep runnning ...
docker run -dt \
--privileged \
-v /path_to_existing_folder_on_host_machine:/root/repo1 \
-e DISPLAY=:0 \
-p 14556:14556/udp \
--name name_container_1 \
name_container_1
echo ... Finished setting up docker and kept it running in the background
```

The folders are synched: if I create a file on the host machine, I can see it from the docker container. However, I get a folder on both the host and the container that is empty.

EDIT: I understood that what I was doing is wrong since mounting a volume from the host machine will effectively "override" files that exist in the container. Therefore, I think that I have to find another solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to mount your host folder like this:

`docker run -v <host-file-system-directory>:<docker-file-system-directory>`

Refer [Access a bash script variable outside the docker container in which the script is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164015/access-a-bash-script-variable-outside-the-docker-container-in-which-the-script-i/58165101#58165101)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this is exactly what I do in my command. The problem is that the creation of the volume erases the content of the folder. I think that maybe volumes are not the right thing to use in this case. Maybe a simpler solution would be, since the folder is a git repo, to develop it on my host machine, commit the changes, test it in the docker container.